# Solve $\sin(x-y)$ using trig identities

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\sin (x) = 1/3$ and $\sec (y) = 29/21$, where $0\le x,y\le\pi/2$, evaluate the expression using trigonometric identities."

I keep going in circles ending up with: something $-\sin(x-y)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin(x-y)= \sin x\cos y - \cos x\sin y$. Can you finish now?

Comment: That's the identity I used that got me into a loop. From there I tried using Cos(x)Sin(y) = 1/2[ sin(x+y) - sin(x-y)] and that led to my loop.

Comment: From there you should continue by calculating $\sin x,\cos x,\sin y, \cos y$. You have enough info to find these numbers.

Comment: I realize I left out an important part of the question. The answer needs to be exact. My guess is that you're supposing I take the given values, find x and y, then plug them into the equation given from the first identity. However, I believe I'm supposed to use identities to continuously convert the given expression until I have it only in terms of Sin(x) and Cos(y). That's what I'm stuck on, as I can solve it without an exact answer.

Comment: You  will get an exact answer. For example since $\sin x=1/3$ you get $\cos x = 2\sqrt{2}/3$. The condition for $\sec y $ will give you $\cos y, \sin y$ and you can plug it all in the expression for $\sin(x-y)$.

Comment: Oh I think I know what you did. Since sin is opposite over hypontenuse, you have two sides to a triangle, solve for the third, and then you have cos x. Is that correct? I haven't done trig in a few years so I was a little slow to catch on.

Comment: Yes, $\cos x =\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin (x-y) = \sin x\cos y - \cos x\sin y$

$\cos x = \pm\sqrt {1-\sin^2 x}$ and $0<x<\frac {\pi}{2}$ tells it is positive.

$\sec y = \frac {29}{21}\implies \cos y = \frac  {21}{29}$ and using similar logic as we did above we find $\sin y$

I will let you put it together.